# Remove padding to the right of a 100% width responsive email design? Error only in iOS 9

Tags: email, responsive-design, ios9, html-email, email-client

I've been turning this design over all day. Basically there's a white bar on the side of my email design that I can not figure out how to remove. It's only present in iOS9 and should have something to do with my html, body, #mainWrapper, or #main. I've tried negative margin adding/removing min-widths.

How do I remove the right bar for a 100% response layout? Any ideas would be helpful.

[Here is a picture of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbX9n.jpg)

And here is my HTML/CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>xxxxx</title>
<style data="noinline">

body {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin:0 !important; 
    padding:0 !important;
}

.appleLink a,
.appleLink,
.telLink {
    color:#646469 !important; 
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

.appleLinkWhite a,
.appleLinkWhite {
    color:#ffffff !important; 
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}

.aBn {
   border-bottom: 0;
}

div #mainWrapper {width:100% !important; table-layout:fixed !important; min-width:100% !important;}

/* MOBILE STYLES */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    
      body[yahoo=yes] {
          margin: 0 !important; 
          padding: 0 !important;
      }
    
    table[class=mobileHide], 
    td[class=mobileHide],
    span[class=mobileHide] {
          display: none !important;
    }
  
      div[class=mobileShow] {
        display: block !important; 
        max-height: none !important;
    }
      
    table[class=mobileShow] {
        display: table !important; 
        max-height: none !important;
    }
    
      a[class=mobileShow] {
        display: inline !important; 
        max-height: none !important;
    }
    
      img[class=mobileShow] {
        display: block !important; 
        max-height: none !important;
    }
    
    table [id=mainWrapper],
    table[id=main],
    table[id=headerWrapper],
    table[id=leadlineWrapper],
    table[id=heroWrapper],
    table[id=messageHeaderWrapper],
    table[id=messageWrapper],
    table[id=ctaWrapper],
    table[id=footerWrapper]{
        margin:0 auto !important;
        width:100% !important; 
        padding:0 !important;
    }
 
 table[id=logoMobile] {
  background:#ffffff;
 }
    
    table[id=logoMobile] img
    table[id=hero] img {
        display: block !important; 
        height:auto !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
    
    table[id=footer] img {
        display: block !important; 
        height:auto !important;
        width:60% !important;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    
        td[id=cta] img {
        display: block !important; 
        height:auto !important;
        width:60% !important;
        margin:0 auto 3px auto;
    }
    
    td[id=messageHeader] {
        margin-top:3px;
    }
    
    td[id=leadline],
    td[id= requiredFooterText] {
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }
    

    td[id=messageHeader],
    td[id=messageBody] {
        font-size: 20px !important;
    }
    
    table[id=bulletList],
    table[id=requiredFooter] {
        width:85% !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
    }
    
}

/* end MOBILE STYLES*/

</style>
<style>

/* DESKTOP STYLES */
.appleLink a,
.appleLink,
.telLink {
    color:#646469 !important; 
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

.appleLinkWhite a,
.appleLinkWhite {
    color:#ffffff !important; 
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

.mobileShow,
.mobileShow img {
    display:none; 
    max-height:0; 
    font-size:0;
}

img {
    display:block; 
    border:0;
}
    
p {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    display:inline;
}

table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table td {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#mainWrapper {
    background: #646469;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

#logoWrapper {
    background: #ffffff;
}

#leadlineWrapper {
    background: #ffffff;
}

#leadline {
    color: #646469;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;    
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#heroWrapper,
#messageHeaderWrapper {
 width: 600px; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 background-color:#e0e0e1;
}

#messageHeader {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color:#e0e0e1;
}

#leadlineWrapper,
#messageWrapper,
#ctaWrapper {
 width: 600px; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 background-color:#ffffff;
}

#messageBody {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    color: #646469;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#messageBody a {
    color: #8b1b3f;
}

#bulletList td {
    vertical-align:top;
    color: #646469;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.bullet {
    width:14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#ctaContainer {
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}

#cta {
    padding:35px;
}

#footerWrapper {
 background-color:#333333; 
 width:600px;
}

#footer {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer img{
    display: inline-block;
}

#requiredFooterText {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* end DESKTOP STYLES*/

</style>
</head>
<body yahoo="yes" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; margin: 0; padding:0;">
<table id="mainWrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center"><tr>
<td>
    <table id="headerWrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td id="logoContainer">
                <table class="mobileHide" id="logoDesktop" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:600px; background-color:#ffffff;"><tr>
<td style="text-transform: none;">
                            <a href="xxxxx" target="_blank">
                                 <img src="https://xxxxx/logo_desktop.jpg" width="600" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #8b1b3f; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-transform: none;" alt="xxxxx"></a>
                         </td>
                      </tr></table>
<!-- /#logoDesktop --><div class="mobileShow">  
                    <table class="mobileShow" id="logoMobile" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tr>
<td style="text-transform: none;">
                                 <a class="mobileShow" href="http://xxxxx" target="_blank">
                                     <img class="mobileShow" src="https://xxxxx/logo_mobile.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #8b1b3f; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-transform: none;" alt="xxxxx"></a>
                             </td>
                          </tr></table>
<!-- /#logoMobile -->
</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>
                <table id="leadlineWrapper" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr>
<td id="leadline">Scenic surroundings and big-city opportunities.</td>
                      </tr></table>
<!-- /#leadlineWrapper -->
</td>
          </tr>
</table>
<!-- /#headerWrapper --><table id="main" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tbody>
<tr>
<td id="heroContainer">
<table id="heroWrapper" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="hero" style="text-transform: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
                <a href="xxxxx" id="auto_lnk_id 3" name="auto_lnk_name 3" target="_blank"> 
                <img alt="xxxxxx" border="0" src="https://xxxxx/hero_msg6.jpg" style="color: #8b1b3f; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; border: 0; width:600px; height:350px;" /></a>
             </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table id="messageHeaderWrapper" align="center"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td id="messageHeader" style="text-transform: none;">[Contact.First Name],<br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae sem finibus, consectetur nunc a, congue purus. Quisque maximus est nec lectus posuere ornare. In sit amet feugiat lectus.</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- /#hero -->
</td>
<!-- /#heroWrapper -->
           </tr>
<tr>
<td id="messageContainer">
                    <table id="messageWrapper" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="messageBody" style="text-transform: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
<strong>Cras euismod.</strong><br />Suspendisse non eros in dolor posuere lobortis. Suspendisse non odio congue, imperdiet diam quis, pretium leo. Curabitur ac nulla elit.<br /><br /><strong>Vestibulum egestas.</strong><br />Curabitur ac convallis erat. Nullam at ultrices eros. Donec ac metus justo. Ut bibendum metus eu sodales commodo.<br /><br /><strong>Praesent eget.</strong><br /> Vivamus varius, augue ac egestas pharetra, leo nibh varius risus, in porta purus nibh a nulla. Donec gravida vitae tellus at accumsan.<br /><br />Etiam nisi orci, vulputate nec blandit at, suscipit ac lorem.
</td>
<!-- /#messageBody --></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- /#messageWrapper -->
</td>
           </tr>
<tr>
<td id="ctaContainer">
        <table id="ctaWrapper" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" id="cta" style="text-transform: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
<a href="xxxxxx" id="auto_lnk_id 5" name="auto_lnk_name 5" target="_blank"> <img alt="xxxxxx" border="0" height="38" src="https://xxxxxx/cta_at_desktop.jpg" style="color: #8b1b3f; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; border: 0; display: block;" width="196" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- /#cta -->
</td>
           </tr>
<tr>
<td id="footerContainer">
        <table id="footerWrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tr>
<td id="footer" style="text-transform: none;" align="center">
             <a href="http://xxxxxx" target="_blank">
                                 <img src="https://xxxxxx/footer_logo.png" width="196" height="42" border="0" style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;" alt="xxxxxx"></a>
                         </td>
                          </tr></table>
<!-- /#hero -->
</td>
<!-- /#heroWrapper -->
           </tr>
</tbody></table>
<!-- /#main --><table id="requiredFooter" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr>
<td id="requiredFooterText">
              This message was sent to <a href="mailto:[Contact.Email]" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:underline;">[Contact.Email]</a> by <a href="xxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:underline;">xxxxxx</a>.<br><br>
           
              xxxxxx<br>
              xxxxxx<br>
              xxxxxx<br>
              xxxxxx<br><br>

              We received your contact information from [Contact._source].<br><a href="xxxxxx" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;"><span style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:underline;">Unsubscribe</span></a> from future email communications from xxxxxx.<br><br><br>
</td>
        </tr></table>
<!-- /#requiredFooter -->
</td>
</tr></table>
<!-- /#mainWrapper --><style data="noinline">@media print{ #_t { background-image: url('https://ajucb1v6.emltrk.com/ajucb1v6?p&d=[Contact.Email]&t=[Campaign.Id]');}} div.OutlookMessageHeader {background-image:url('https://ajucb1v6.emltrk.com/ajucb1v6?f&d=[Contact.Email]&t=[Campaign.Id]')} table.moz-email-headers-table {background-image:url('https://ajucb1v6.emltrk.com/ajucb1v6?f&d=[Contact.Email]&t=[Campaign.Id]')} blockquote #_t {background-image:url('https://ajucb1v6.emltrk.com/ajucb1v6?f&d=[Contact.Email]&t=[Campaign.Id]')} #MailContainerBody #_t {background-image:url('https://ajucb1v6.emltrk.com/ajucb1v6?f&d=[Contact.Email]&t=[Campaign.Id]')}</style>
<div id="_t"></div>
<img src="https://ajucb1v6.emltrk.com/ajucb1v6?d=[Contact.Email]&t=[Campaign.Id]" width="1" height="1" border="0">
</body>
</html>
```

All of the images/text have been removed to protect my client.

I'm just hoping its a stupid color/semicolon error or something, and not the ['magical padding' that Litmus has discussed over new additions to iOS9 Apple Mail](https://litmus.com/blog/what-email-designers-need-to-know-about-ios-9).